# Bouncing ball between 4 walls destination algorithm

Tags: algorithm, animation, collision

I'm trying to implement an animation of a ball bouncing between 4 perpendicular walls, being the speed of the ball constant. The problem is, the framework I'm using requires me to tell the origin and the destination of the ball each time it collides with a wall.

In the moment of the collision, I have access to both the ball's current and previous positions of contact with the walls. Given the coordinates x_min, x_max, y_min and y_max of the walls, and these two positions of the ball, what is the simplest way to calculate its next position?

All the algorithms I thought about followed kind of a brute force approach, with many if-else statements... I wonder if there is some elegant way of handling this.

Comment: what do you mean by next position?  are you doing time steps?  or do you mean where will it next hit another wall? and what do you mean by "origin and the destination"?  can you draw a picture, or give some examples with real numbers?  typically when bouncing off a wall you just change the sign of one of the velocities (the perpendicular one).  that is all that is needed...

Comment: I mean the next point of collision with a wall. There is no time step or velocity involved - only telling, once the ball hits a ball, where it should hit the next time. The comment by acfrancis pictures exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[sorry, this is incomplete - i would have posted it as a comment, but it's too large and involves ascii art.  i may delete it later.]

if you want a compact, elegant approach it's probably easier to think of the ball as continuing in a straight line, crossing over a repeated pattern of rectangles.

```
+------+------+--*---+
|      |      | *    |
|      |      |*     |
+------+------*------+
|      |     *|      |
|      |    * |      |
+------+---*--+------+
|      |  *   |      |
|      | *    |      |
+------+*-----+------+
|      *      |      |
|     *|      |      |
+----*-+------+------+
|   *  |      |      |
|  *   |      |      |
+-*----+------+------+
```

(you need to reflect the rectangles, but then get the bounce "for free").

and i am pretty sure that you could then use something similar to [bresenham's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm)
 to calculate the points of intersection.

[thanks for the vote, but i have to say i think this could be a world of pain to get right.  tracking reflections, particularly if exactly hit a corner, is going to be tricky... sometimes it's easier to live with ugly code!]

Comment: At a first glance, this approach seems indeed simpler to implement. I have to think a little about the best way to use it, but it sounds like the elegant way I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the previous bounce was off the left wall at position (x_min, y_prev) and the current bounce is off the top wall at (x_curr, y_max). The next bounce should be off the right wall at (x_max, y_next) where:

```
y_next = y_max - (y_max - y_prev) * (x_max - x_curr) / (x_curr - x_min)
```

It's simple geometry that the triangle defined by (previous bounce, top left corner, current bounce) is similar (same shape but different size)  to the triangle (current bounce, top right corner, next bounce). Like this:

```
+--*----+
| / \   |
|/   \  |
*     \ |
|      \|
|       *
|       |
+-------+
```

If y_next is less than y_min, that means the ball will hit the bottom wall before the right wall. The will happen at (x_next, y_min) where:

```
x_next = x_curr + (x_curr - x_min) * (y_max - y_min) / (y_max - y_prev)
```

Something like this:

```
+--*------+
| / \     |
|/   \    |
*     \   |
|      \  |
+-------*-+
```

Comment: I thought about something similar, but still, sounds like a brute force approach - first you have to find out in which wall the ball is, then write a line equation for the case of a collision with the floor/ceiling, and another for a collision with the left/right wall. And then there is still the case of a collision with one of the corners... Well, I guess there is not a much better way to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether this is similar to what you have in mind, but my idea is to basically calculate the position as if there's no wall, and then flip the applicable coordinate using the wall as the centre point.

So, first you calculate:

```
new
 \
  \
   \
---------
     \
      \
      old
```

Then you translate it to:

```
---------
   / \
  /   \
 /    old
new
```

Pseudo-code:

```
newX = oldX + xInc
newY = oldY + yInc

if newX < 0
  newX = -newX

if newY < 0
  newY = -newY

if newX > maxX
  newX = maxX - (newX - maxX)
  // or 2*maxX - newX

if newY > maxY
  newY = maxY - (newY - maxY)
  // or 2*maxY - newY
```